# Kusto datetime range() with using variable Input for [step]

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

```
range(todatetime(NextTestDate), datetime(2023-03-29), 180d)
```

here instead of 180d can I use a variable as a step to add days. something like {x}d, instead of hardcoded value.

Comment: What's your use of `range()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be solved with a simple multiplication by timespan

```
let p_step  = 3;
let p_from  = startofday(ago(10d));
let p_to    = now();
print range(p_from, p_to, p_step * 1d)
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| ["2022-07-27T00:00:00.0000000Z","2022-07-30T00:00:00.0000000Z","2022-08-02T00:00:00.0000000Z","2022-08-05T00:00:00.0000000Z"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAzXMTQqAIBBA4X2nmOUYLpKW0VlC8IfAHBkHotuXhtvHx0teoBxVfAHYYd2m1ENgulqoYlkoOPugjYRmcUoNIwTQTKYbv1j4zAJsc/T4D3RHevxnME69aok/0XAAAAA=)

Comment: Hi David, thank you for this suggestion. But Im getting a number as a variable input from a table and I need the NextTestDate to loop with this number. If my NextTestDate wasnt a date then I could have easily used that number to loop. But since its a date i need to add 'd' after this number in order to increase the date, otherwise its an infinite loop.

Comment: See updated answer